# Перезапуск сцены в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я понимаю, что весь интернет забит этими методами перезапуска. Но я перепробовал все, и не добился нужного результата. МНЕ НУЖНО, ЧТОБЫ СЦЕНА ПЕРЕЗАПУСКАЛАСЬ ПОЛНОСТЬЮ!!! То есть все значения, которые изменялись в течение игры, обновились и вернулись к изначальным, то бишь скрипт начинался сначала. Я пробовал обращаться к другим скриптам, для их изменения, но безрезультатно. Поэтому пришел к выводу, что мне нужен АБСОЛЮТНЫЙ перезапуск сцены.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Operations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool lose = false; // переменная проигрыша (да/нет)
    private Animator anim; // Ну оно понятно ;)

    void Start(){
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); // все запуски анимации
        anim.SetBool("ButtonPressed", false);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy"){ // просмотр: попал ли противник на объект защиты или нет?
            lose = true; // если да, то - проиграл
        }
        if(lose == true){ // а если проиграл, то проигрывание анимации и небольшое ожидание, для понимания того, что происходит
            anim.SetBool("ButtonPressed", true);
            Invoke("LoadLoseScene", 1.8f);
        }
    }

    void LoadLoseScene(){ // после ожидания загрузка сцены проигрыша
        SceneManager.LoadScene("LoseScene");
    }

    public void PlayAgain(){ // функция для кнопки - если нажал, то можешь начать сначала
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameScene");
    }

    void Awake(){ // <= сбрасывается переменная проигрыша здесь 
        lose = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Что такое Awake()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) для начала.

Comment: Метод, который вызывается до старта, потому что если менять значение переменной lose в методе Start, то счет очков неточен